# Restore inner fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making an app that in a certain FragmentActivity has a Tabhost hosting 2 Fragments.
One of them must have either a layout A showing up or a layout B showing up, while the other one has always the same layout.

- FragmentActivity

  - Fragment1 (first tab)

    - LayoutA
    - LayoutB
  - Fragment2 (second tab)

    - LayoutC

In order to wrap the control of both layouts in separate modules, I made two Fragments, namely FragmentA and FragmentB, that use LayoutA and LayoutB respectively, making the activity look like this:

- FragmentActivity

  - Fragment1 (first tab)

    - FragmentA

      - LayoutA
    - FragmentB

      - LayoutB
  - Fragment2 (second tab)

    - LayoutC

The problem I have is that I cannot make this stable against both:

- the user leaving the app when first tab is shown
- the user navigates to tab 2 and then back to tab 1

At first my code for Fragment1 looked like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    view.setId(1);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(1, mCurrentFragment, "f1");
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(mCurrentFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Inside onStop I remove the fragment in order to attach it to the new FrameLayout created in OnCreateView when the Fragment restarts next time.
The problem with this code is that apparently I cannot do any transactions when user leaves the app, so it crashes with.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {my.package/my.package.MainTabHost}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

To solve the problem, I changed the removing of the fragment just before I try to add it to the FragmentTransaction in onStart:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    view.setId(1);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("f1") != null) {
        ft.remove(mCurrentFragment);
    }
    ft.add(1, mCurrentFragment, "f1");
    ft.commit();
}
```

This code has the other problem. Switching from the first tab to the second and then coming back to the first shows a blank layout for Fragment1.

Note: I set all fragments to retain their state.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I used the second code. I had to this sequence of steps inside onStart:
 - detach the fragment
 - add it to the new view
 - attach it